# Graph time series in seconds with dygraph

Tags: r, time, axis, series, scrollable

I get data from a device recording roughly every 8 to 10 ms. Here is how the raw data looks like (with Time in seconds):

```
> data
             Time       Raw     
    1 0.004061294 0.7384716
    2 0.012264294 1.9172491 
    3 0.020467294 2.2663045 
    4 0.028670294 1.1509293 
    5 0.037858294 1.6099277 
    6 0.048030294 0.7834101
...
```

The file is very long, and I would like to inspect it first with a scrollable x-axis. Therefore, I treated this data as a time series and used the dygraphs package to visualize it.

```
data_ts <- as.ts(data$Raw)
dygraph(ts_data, main="Raw signal") %>%
  dyRangeSelector()
```

The result is great, but I would like to be able to see the values of the x-axis in seconds (or miliseconds). So far, nothing is displayed and I can't wrap my head around the problem. I guess it may have something to do with the fact that I haven't specified the unit of the time series. Or that my data does not fit the requirement of a time series, since the time intervals are slightly irregular.

[image: dyRangeSelector_Graph]

Thanks for your help! 
Any other solutions that would allow to scroll the x-axis are also welcome.